# How can I find out the value of $(ProjectDir)?

Tags: visual-studio

Where can I execute and find out the value of `$(ProjectDir)`?

Comment: A bit more detail would help. In what context are you asking? Visual Studio? MSBuild? Something else? Where do you need the value and why do you need to find out what it is?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Do a pre/post build step.

Example:

```
echo $(ProjectDir)
```

Answer (score 118):

To find out what it is right now (rather than at build time, where it may be different depending on what is going on):

- right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, select *Properties*
- select the *Build Events* tab
- click the *Edit pre-build* or *Edit post-build* button, either is fine
- in the window that pops up, click the *Macros* button
- scroll down the list till you find `ProjectDir`, in the next pane is its actual value

Comment: For "click the Edit pre-build", I had to edit the Command Line to get the "Macros" button. Using VS 2010.

Comment: @devopsEMK I don't use the community edition (never have) - possibly it is a feature that isn't available in that edition.

Comment: I use VS Community 2013 Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5 and indeed the macro button is there.

Comment: VS 2022 does not have any "Edit pre-build" or "Edit post-build" button. You can go to any property on any tab, select the down-arrow on the right, click "<Edit...>" and then "Macros".

Answer (score 26):

The answer from slugster did not work for me (most possible my fault).

In Visual Studio 2008

1. right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, select *Properties*
2. Go to *Configuration Properties* and then to *Debugging*
3. Click on the arrow in the *Command* Field and click the *Edit* Button
4. In *Edit* clik "*Macros*>>" You will see there the values of ProjectDir... etc..

Answer (score 16):

In Visual Studio 2015, you can find ProjectDir by clicking on Macros in additional Include Directories and then clicking on Macros (for me there was nothing in Build Events) :
[image]

Comment: Still valid for VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Open the project properties (Alter+Enter) and then go to "Build Events", select any of the build events, then select "Command Line", click "Edit", then press the "Macros >>" button.

[image]

Comment: This capture helps me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the path to the directory containing *.vcxproj file.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties:

> The directory of the project (defined as drive + path); includes the
> trailing backslash ''.

Comment: Update the link from MSDN to MS docs-->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

Same here in Visual Studio 2019, you can find ProjectDir by clicking on Macros in additional Include Directories and then clicking on Macros (for me there was nothing in Build Events), like the answer in above Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> External Tools
create command for Powershell.exe or Csc.exe
copy exe to c:\ for shorter paths
Name it and check Prompt for arguments

now click Tools -> Click name of your tool
with dialog displayed, click Argument button and choose $(ProjectDir) or whatever.
Your $(ProjectDir) is displayed in Command Line after Powershell.exe or csc.exe
Clear Arguments and click argument button again
Your next selection is display again after command (repeat to view all 16 environment variables.

this is without executing command but command is required to save.

if you use csc.exe from this path
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe"
copy Roslyn folder to
C:\Roslyn
csc.exe needs other files to work, you need whole directory.
Roslyn folder is only 34 Mb