# getting the value of $(ProjectDir), $(SolutionDir) in a vcproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vcproj

Is it possible to get the value of `$(ProjectDir)` or `$(SolutionDir)` programatically outside Visual Studio? My scenario is I need to read a vcproj file as a text file and get its properties like the outputdirectory etc.. problem is some properties contain environment variables like $(SolutionDir) and the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you found out that looking at the .vcproj file isn't enough.  You need to know the .sln file as well.  You're kinda stuck until you resolve this.  Visual Studio will always create a .sln file when it loads a .vcproj file and cannot find a matching .sln.  Maybe you want to do that too.

Comment: I dont have a problem with the solution file, I can read the .sln format fine. I just need to get the value of the variable $(ProjectDir),$(SolutionDir).e.g taken from a vc proj file *** OutputDirectory="$(ProjectDir)$(ConfigurationName)"

Comment: Well, you know the values, $(ProjectDir) is the directory where you found the .vcproj file, $(SolutionDir) is the directory where you found the .sln file.

Comment: I see how about $(ConfigurationName) what does it mean?, also I have got one project where OutputDirectory="$(ProjectDir)Bin" does it mean e.g C:\MYprojectDir\Bin

Comment: That's a selection made when you build.  Debug or Release by default.  And yes.

Comment: Hi Sorry for bringing this up again but is there a way to determine $(ConfigurationName) wether DEbug or Releae just by looking in the vcproj file, if not can you please suggest

Comment: No, this is stored in the hidden .suo file, you cannot read it.  It is random anyway, whatever was last used in the IDE.

Comment: No one actually answered the OP's question. I, for one, would like to know how to access the value of these many macro values. Yes, you can sort of figure out what they "should" mean, but how can you actually print/debug/watch the value each contains and know with certainty what string, say, $(SolutionDir) is resolving to?

Comment: This post answered the question for me--sort of. You're not actually printing the value programmatically but you can see it in the Visual Studio IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423538/executing-projectdir