# Visual Studio Extension: Getting Macro Values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macros, vs-extensibility

I am creating a small extension that gets passed a string that can contain visual studio macros ($(ProjectDir), $(LocalDebuggerCommand), ... ), is there a way to use the macro in c# or c++ code?

**Side Note**:
I have seen solutions which involve creating preprocessor entries. The problem I have with this solution is I can't manually add all the macros because I don't know which macros will be passed to the extension.

Comment: please visit [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: You mean like [`$(ProjectDir)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423538/how-can-i-find-out-the-value-of-projectdir)?

Comment: Yip, $(ProjectDir), $(LocalDebuggerCommand), ...