# Show current folder for ifstream in debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am debugging an executable which tries to load a file using

```
ifstream is("filename");
```

This fails because in the 'current folder' this file seems to be missing. I am pretty sure the file is in the folder containing the project and solution and the working directory is set to project-dir.

**Question**: is there a way to show the folder where ifstream will look for the file in the debugger?

---

Edit 1: 
Getting information about the current project dir can be done like this:

[How can I find out the value of $(ProjectDir)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423538/how-can-i-find-out-the-value-of-projectdir)

---

Edit 2: 
The current working dir can be obtained like this:

```
 char * dir = _getcwd(NULL, 0);
```

I have not found a way to get this information in the debugger without recompiling which would be much nicer.

Comment: If you go to where you define your working directory, you can click on Macros. There you can check where $ProjectDir is referencing, and check if your file is actually there. If not, you move the file or change the working directory.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Are you perhaps running as an admin?

Comment: @remi thanks, i found the error. I would be nice to be able to see the current dir during debugging.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Current dir is shown among process properties in Process Explorer.

Comment: @VTT can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is a tool available from microsoft.com

It will show the active directory of all running processes.

[image]